# Superscripts too high after macros defined with \DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: spacing, superscripts, mathtools

I have a macro for absolute value (using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`):

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

This works great in terms of adjusting the size of fences etc. But the superscript position when I use `\abs{x}^2` is too high. See the following:

[image: PDF output]

<s>Any idea if this is a bug or not, or how I can fix it?</s>
***Edit:** It appears that the above behavior due to the fact that `DeclarePairedDelimiter` calls `\mathclose` / makes a subformula. I don't know if this was a design choice or not -- but I would certainly like to know if there is an easy way to work around it.*

Here's my code for the above.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage{varwidth,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
  \begin{preview}\begin{varwidth}{360pt}
    The superscript following \verb'\abs{x}' is higher than that following \verb'\lvert x\rvert'.
    Here is an example:

    \begin{center}
      \verb'\abs{x}^2 \lvert x\rvert^2' produces $\abs{x}^2 \lvert x\rvert^2$.
    \end{center}
    The same happens in displayed math:
    \begin{equation*}
      \abs{x}^2 \lvert x\rvert^2
    \end{equation*}
  \end{varwidth}\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a design choice in mathtools. Not all users know `\rvert` is better than `|`, so we help them, also it helps us if someone wanted to use `)(`as the delimiter pair. Short of repeating the fenced material in a `\vpahntom` after the fence, I don't know a better method.

But, in this case, as you are using the proper left and right fences, there is an out:

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\abs}{nostar}{#1#2#3}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I didn't get what you mean by someone wanting to use `)(` as the delimiter pair? Do you mean use the parenthesis in the wrong order?

Comment: @gi1242 if ( is the right delimiter in a construction like this (let's call it foo) then the minus in `\foo{x} - 2` comes out wrong as ( has the class of a math open and then the minus following it is unitary not additional (wrong spacing). So when you remove the explicit you need to be sure the right delimiter **is** of type math closing (rvert is)

Comment: Addition: I meant to write:_if you remove the explicit `\mathclose`..._

Comment: @gi1242 please note that this code will produce an error in the upcomming `mathtools` update. I had to split `nostar` into two separate macros. Attempting to change `nostar` will now give an error. On the other hand your original problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

`DeclarePairedDelimiter` produces a subformula. **EDIT** as @Daleif suggested this is due to `DeclarePairedDelimiter` to call `\mathclose` on the right brace.

This is equivalent of using braces (`{` and `}`), which also produce math subformulas, which can cause alignment issues sometimes. (Incidentally, that's why you don't usually have adjacent braces `{}`) in math mode.

See following examples:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}

    \begin{gather}
      \left|x\right|^2 \lvert x\rvert^2 \\
      \abs{x}^{2} \lvert x\rvert^{2} \\
      {|x|}^{2} \lvert x\rvert^{2} 
    \end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Producing:

[image]

You can clearly see that the second example (which is your text) and the subformula produce the same alignment.

It seems that the exponent is applied to the whole subformula, and not carried as the exponent of your variable.

Comment: @Mico Yup, that's caused by `DeclarePairedDelimiter` creating a subformula, thus I guess that the exponent is applied to the fence and not to the variable. I corrected my post

Comment: It seems to be due to the fact that `\abs` is using `\mathclose` on the right delimiter. Unstarred left/right is not used

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the subformula has the same alignment of subscripts. is there a way I can get around it? That is can I get `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` to not create a subformula...?