# Missing middle delimiters when reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper is used

Tags: delimiters, mathtools

I'm using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` (from `mathtools`) to define a `\paren` macro as follows:

```
\providecommand{\given}{\:\vert\:}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\paren[1]{(}{)}{%
  \renewcommand{\given}{\:\delimsize\vert\:}#1%
}
```

This works as expected. But, following the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364308/superscripts-too-high-after-macros-defined-with-declarepaireddelimiter), I used `\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper` to fix the position of sub/superscripts that follow:

```
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\paren}{nostar}{#1#2#3}
```

Now using `\paren{a \given b}` produces *(a b)*, instead of *(a | b)*. (Ie the `\given` symbol is omitted entirely). Using `\paren[\big]{a \given b}` or `\paren*{a \given b}` work just fine though.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: Using `\paren[\relax]{a \given b}` also works as expected. It only fails when the size argument is omitted entirely.

Comment: It happens that `\MHempty`, which is the default value when the optional argument is missing, is redefined to `\@gobble` at some point: this is done on purpose, but apparently it is done at the wrong time.

Comment: Thanks. After experimenting a bit, I'm convinced it is a bug. I'll report it. Any idea if there is a simple work-around...?

Comment: We need the `\let\MHempty\@gobble` to remove the addition of l/r when there is no scaler. I think the easiest to to is to set `\MHempty` back to `{}` after we have used it in the front and end scalers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg mentions this is due to `\MHempty` being redefined to `\@gobble` for the surrounding fences. This is usually done via `\mathopen/close{...}` which acts as a group and this `\@gobble` is localised. With the definition of the wrapper, the `\mathopen/close` and the grouping is gone and `\delimsize` which points to `\MHempty` when there is no scaler, is now `\@gobble` which eats the middle part.

The easiest method for this to works without grouping is to set `\MHempty` back to `{}` after its use in the outer fences.

The code below seems to work.

Please note that in the next release there will be three wrappers, autoscaled, non-scaled and scaled, where the non-scaled will use `\mathopen/close...` not `\mathopen/close{...}` which has side effects when no scalers are used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\MHInternalSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\def\MHempty{}
\def\DeclarePairedDelimiterX#1[#2]#3#4#5{%
  \@ifdefinable{#1}{
    \MT_paired_delimx_arg_test:n{#2}
    \MT_delim_default_inner_wrappers:n{#1}
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      \newcommand
        \@xp\csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:\endcsname
        [#2]
        {
          \begingroup
            \def\delimsize{\middle}
            %\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left#3 #5 \aftergroup\egroup\right#4
            \@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star_wrapper:nnn}
              {\left#3}{#5}{\right#4}
          \endgroup
        }
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      \newcommand
        \@xp\csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:\endcsname
        [1][\MHempty]
      {
        \begingroup
        \def\delimsize{##1}
        \@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar_inner:}
      }
    \@xp\@xp\@xp
      \newcommand
        \@xp\csname MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar_inner:\endcsname
        [#2]
        {
          %\mathopen{%
          %  \let\MHempty\@gobble
          %  \@xp\@xp\@xp\csname\@xp\MH_cs_to_str:N \delimsize l\endcsname #3}
          %#5
          %\mathclose{%
          %  \let\MHempty\@gobble
          %  \@xp\@xp\@xp\csname\@xp\MH_cs_to_str:N \delimsize r\endcsname #4}
          \@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar_wrapper:nnn}
          {
            \let\MHempty\@gobble
            \@xp\@xp\@xp\csname\@xp\MH_cs_to_str:N \delimsize l\endcsname #3
            \def\MHempty{}
          }
          {#5}
          {
            \let\MHempty\@gobble
            \@xp\@xp\@xp\csname\@xp\MH_cs_to_str:N \delimsize r\endcsname #4
            \def\MHempty{}
          }
          \endgroup
        }
    \DeclareRobustCommand{#1}{
      \@ifstar
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _star:}}
        {\@nameuse{MT_delim_\MH_cs_to_str:N #1 _nostar:}}
    }
  }
}
\makeatother
\MHInternalSyntaxOff

\providecommand{\given}{\:\vert\:}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\paren[1]{(}{)}{%
  \renewcommand{\given}{\:\delimsize\vert\:}
  #1%
}
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper{\paren}{nostar}{#1#2#3}


\begin{document}

\[
\paren{ a \given b }
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks a lot! From what you say above, do I understand that you are going to include a fix in future releases of MathTools?

Comment: @gi1242 of course