# Which controls the kerning and position of superscript/subscript, LaTeX or font itself?

Tags: fonts, subscripts, kerning

I want to adjust the global kerning (and also the position) of superscript and subscript when using some particular font in math mode. I know the kerning between *letters* is designed in the font itself, hence if we want to adjust it globally, we need to go into the font itself, such as modify them in FontForge. However, I'm not sure what is the *script* cases (e.g. `$x^n$` or `$a_6$`). Is the kerning (i.e. horizontal width) and position (i.e., higher or lower) controlled by font itself or the (La)TeX engines? If it is the latter case, how to adjust them?

Comment: Just some background information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371499/subtleties-in-placing-superscripts-explaining-what-tex-is-actually-doing and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371702/subtleties-in-placing-subscript-explaining-what-tex-is-actually-doing.

Comment: See appendix G (I think) of The TeX Book.